# sending email on local machine is not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I am using my gmail's email account to send emails in asp.net website. It works fine on hosting server but it donot works if I try to sent email on loclserver.

Please guide me what I should do to make it sending emails even on localserver ? Do I need to install some smtp server on my local machine ? I have not installed any smtp server on my machine. How and where from I can get smtp server and kindly also guide how I can do its setting to use on local machine.

Thnaks

**Here is my Code**

```
 public string SendEmail(Email email)
    {
        string errmsg = null;

        if (dt != null)
        {
            try
            {
                dt = systemrep.GetSystemInfo();
                dr = dt.Rows[0];
                From = dr["nm_EmailFrom"].ToString();
                SMTP = dr["nm_SMTP"].ToString();
                Port = dr["amt_Port"].ToString();
                EmailId = dr["nm_emailUserId"].ToString();
                EmailPassword = dr["nm_emailPassword"].ToString();
                DefaultCredations = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["ind_Credentials"].ToString());
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                NetworkCredential mailAuthentication = new NetworkCredential(EmailId, EmailPassword);
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress(email.To));
                message.From = new MailAddress(From);
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.Subject = email.Subject;
                message.Body = email.Message;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = DefaultCredations;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Port = 25;
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.Host = SMTP;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(EmailId, EmailPassword);


                smtp.Send(message);
            }
            catch (SmtpException smtpEx)
            {

                errmsg = string.Format("alert('There was a problem in sending the email: {0}');", smtpEx.Message.Replace("'", "\\'"));
            }
            catch (Exception generalEx)
            {
                errmsg = string.Format("alert('There was a general problem: {0}');", generalEx.Message.Replace("'", "\\'"));
            }
        }
        else
            errmsg = "An error accured whilte getting email settings from database, process couldn't be completed";

        return errmsg;
    }

}
```

Comment: Refer to this blog post. It shows you how to send email through smtp client using gmail
[Click Here](http://frazsundal.blogspot.com/2009/12/send-email-through-smtp-client.html) to view

Comment: @Pauli sorry I am new what does mean by value of smtp how I cna check it ?

Comment: it is also not working on locakmachine

Comment: you don't actually know what host your sending your email through? You have a varible named SMTP that you are assigning to smtp.Host. What is the value of it?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do a bit more research before you dive in and set up your own SMTP server to relay to gmail.

If your 'hosting server' is located at DOMAIN.COM, and you are sending email messages from HAANSI@DOMAIN.COM, or if you authenticate with GMail as "HAANSI@DOMAIN.COM" you may run into some difficulties getting the messages to send from localserver, even if the code is bug-free and you've set up the SMTP server correctly.  AFAIK, Gmail does not relay, and is pretty strict on authentication (using secure authentication and everything).

I recommend you send the messages from your hosting server where things are already working well today, if possible.

In fact, you might even consider a slightly different tactic where you send querystring params off a script running on that server, and let the script do the sending... or save a file to the server and have your program pick it up to send... or any other method that gets the data over to the server, and lets the server send it out.

Comment: I dont want to set my own smtp server, I am just asking do I need to set smtp server on local machine before sending emails on local machine. I want to use google account on local machine.

Comment: His question is about not sending email from his local machine through GMAIL. It could even be a firewall issue.

Comment: @Shoban no firewall or antivirous on system

Comment: Hi Haansi - Sorry I wasn't clear.  I was trying to let you know how you *might* be able to do it.  Without an SMTP server set-up, you're not going to be able to do it.  Gmail won't allow any random person to write a few lines of code and use their service to send out email messages (for obvious reasons).

Comment: We can SEND email through gmail if you use proper authentication. He also says "It works fine on hosting server" which clearly means he is using proper authentication.